# Visual Issue with Laravel 8 pagination link() method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Im trying to find out why blade isn't working right with this method and not showing properly in my webserver:

[image]

```
{{$posts->links()}}
```

Then this is my controller method who gets the data from the database and gives to the view the data

```
public function index(){
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('dashboard.post.index',['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a css 404 issue, have you checked the console for any error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192277/how-to-solve-pagination-problem-in-laravel-8-0 seems to have the same issue so maybe keep an eye out for any answers that are given there too

Comment: Laravel 8 removed Bootstrap in favor of TailwindCSS.  Updating from Laravel 7 to 8 requires the answer provided by ruan  viviers below.

Answer (score 5):

what worked for me was adding the following to the app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file

```
//call paginator 
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

and then in the boot function add

```
Paginator::useBootstrap();
```

the file should look something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

//call paginator 
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //...
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //fix for pagination making weird oversize by using bootstraps paginator
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: also works for Laravel 7

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this issue as well, I use the below solution and it worked fine for me on laravel 8. Hope it will be helpful.

```
{!! $posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') !!}
```