# PHP / Laravel 8.0 : UI of link method on Paginator instance is broken after upgrading from version 7.25

Tags: laravel, hyperlink, pagination

I switched my laravel app from 7.25 to 8.0. Now I am facing pagination problem.

`{{ $download->links() }}`

in controller

`$download = Download::paginate(2);`

Yes, it is working well but the UI is broken now.

[image error ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KckHD.png)

Comment: Its a css issue. Check console, you will find error

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel 8 more options were added how pagination can be displayed.

This instruction https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap should help.

Comment: finally i found someone that saved my day , thank you so much

Comment: @kerolesMonsef can you please specify how you solved it?

Comment: @MartinPfeffer
just add ```Paginator::useBootstrap();``` in ```AppServiceProvider```

Answer (score 3):

Go to `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`

add

`public function boot() { Paginator::useBootstrap(); }`

and import

`use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they have made changes to the UI (bootstrap) in the latest, version.

I would suggest you to create a custom UI for that links by yourself. Use the following commands to publish the pagination views to resource directory and make some changes accordingly.

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

and points to your custom view with the following line of code:

`{{ $paginator->links('view.name') }}`

which is in your case `{{$download->links('view.name')}}`